# mov's play without sound unless in iMovie

Tags: audio, video, camera, quicktime, imovie

I have a lot of videos from a Canon mini dv video camera. I imported them from my camera into iMovie, so now I have them all in an event. The videos play perfectly fine in iMovie.

I tried to copy all of these videos onto an external drive. To do this, I view the event in Finder, show package contents, and open original media; in that folder are the individual mov's that I want.

However, when I open these videos in, say, Quicktime, there is no sound. Maybe I am missing some codecs, but I want these videos and their sound to work like normal and not to rely on rare dependencies.

What can I do to fix these videos?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on What you want the videos as, if you want, you can use the iMovie theater to export them (Recommended), or as a last resort, you could Screen record Each Video (Not Recommended). If you want to export each individual video, you can do it using iMovie theater by making a new movie for each Video.

Comment: Can I use the iMovie theater to export all the individual videos in the event as an mov or mp4?

Comment: You could export all the individual videos, but depending on the number, it may be tedious. Editing the answer

Comment: @Daniel Does that answer your question now?

Comment: I have a *lot* of videos, so doing something individually for each is very, very tedious. Is there some way to simply do something to the videos in finder to make their sound play?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading a free batch mov to mp4 converter and dragging in all the videos from the iMovie event in Finder.